# How to allocate a static IP for an internal load balancer in Azure AKS

Tags: azure-aks

The document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb) describes how to create an AKS service with an internal load balancer associated with it. It explains how to assign an explicit IP address to this load balancer and states that the chosen IP "must not already be assigned to a resource." My question is how do I allocate this IP? The CLI command

```
az network public-ip create
```

can be used to allocate a public IP but there is no equivalent command

```
az network private-ip create
```

What is the correct procedure for allocating a private static IP in Azure?

Peter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such command to create a static private IP for an internal load balancer in Azure AKS as Azure Networking has no visibility into the service IP range of the Kubernetes cluster, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-advanced-networking#frequently-asked-questions).

Actually, you could add the **loadBalancerIP** property to the load balancer YAML manifest to [specific a private IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#specify-an-ip-address) for an internal load balancer. When you do that, the specified IP address must reside in the **same subnet as the AKS cluster** and must not already be assigned to a resource. You could check the subnets where your deploy the aks cluster, then select one of the available addresses from the subnet address range, which should not overlap with the other IP address from connected devices.

Hope this will help you.